# Asm bswap in C Windows code

Tags: c, windows, assembly, porting

I'm porting C code where there are direct `__asm__` calls from Linux to Windows. Those calls are not supported by the Visual Studio compiler so I'm looking for a Windows version of the following GCC call:

`__asm__("bswapl %0" : "=r" (val) : "0" (val))`

Could someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this piece of Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3140177.aspx) - Winodws has byte-swapping functions. You may also find [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/assembler/inline/asm?view=vs-2017) helpful, it talks about `__asm` in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Ankush, I used `_byteswap_ulong` and `_byteswap_uint64`, as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3140177.aspx), and its seems to be working ok. Thanks!